# How to remove "Windows 10"'s Adobe Flash Player?

Tags: windows-10, flash

Since youtube works well without Adobe Flash, there is no reason to carry the risks of having a Flash Player (which has a horrible track-record with regards to security vulnverabilities). Therefore inside my VM of Windows10 I have never ever needed Flash and surely not installed it.

To my suprise there seems to be that Microsoft cares to keep a Flash Player arround (I cannot imagine why, cosidering those Redmond guys are quire proficient in creating security bugs of their own??)

Anyway as the screenshot shows there is a Software named "Adobe Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1903". How can I remove this unnecessary additional security nightmare from my windows?

[image]

Adobe Flash Player does not feature in the least of Windows "features"
found Under `Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows Features on or off`

[image]

Comment: [Completely uninstall & remove Adobe Flash Player from Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-completely-uninstall-remove-adobe-flash-player-from-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Flash has been integrated with Edge since the beginning of Windows 10. So this is not new. If you do not use Flash, go to Edge, Settings (click on ... ). Scroll down to Settings, open Settings,Advanced, and then deselect Adobe Flash. Then Flash will not be used.

Comment: To build on @John's answer, the Flash Player available from Adobe and the Flash Player embedded within Chromium browsers are not the same piece of software (Flash Player will never show under Uninstall/Remove Programs, as it's not installed, but a browser plugin that's been sandboxed and locked down by the respective browser).

Comment: If I surfed the web with the offer of Mozilla (firefox) gecko engine I would not have to worry about the update and flash, right?

Comment: Yes, so far as I know that is correct